# The most distant node for each node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Is there any way to find the most distant node for every node in binary tree. I know about problem of diemeter of the tree, but that is query about every node. I would like to have algorithm working in `O(nlogn)` for n-node tree.

Comment: a directed or undirected tree?

Comment: Most distant node, is that most distant from all other nodes?

Comment: @UmNyobe undirected.

Comment: @Dirk Horsten For every node it could be another node.

Comment: Do you apply weights to your edges?

Answer (score 3):

In two steps:

- Calculate the most distant child and its distance for each node. This can be done by traversing the tree (O(n)) post-order.
- For each node: check the most distant child for this node and each of its parents (adding one extra distance as you walk toward the root). Pick the largest. O(n logn).

Modification: If you store the most distant child and its distance for both the left and right subtrees, you can traverse the tree pre-order and get all the results in O(n).

Example (without marking *which* node is the most distant.. implementation detail):

```
       3.2       root
      /   \
     1*2  0.1
     / \    \
   0.0 1.1  0.0
       / \
     0.0 0.0
```

Starting from the root - longest distance through parent is 0.

- The longest distance is max(0,2,3) = 3.
- Recursing to left: passing max(0,2)+1 as the longest distance through parent.
- Recursing to right: passing max(0,3)+1 as the longest distance through parent.

At any point there are three possibilities: longest route goes though the parent, it's in the left subtree or in the right subtree. All these distances are readily available when visiting the node.

Comment: pre-order?  details please.

Comment: Ok that's assuming you cannot go up. Otherwise you have to do two runs. first compute for each node , d(left), d(right), then do `d = min(d(left), d(right), parent.left == this ? parent.d(parent.right) : parent.d(parent.left))`

Comment: @Karoly Horvath, you are limiting to binary trees. Is that essential?

Comment: @DirkHorsten: Admittedly OP's question does say "Is there any way to find the most distant node for every node in binary tree"

Comment: @DirkHorsten: Since it's trivial to handle other cases, no it isn't. In fact, you can push the count one level below, reducing the costs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't fully understand idea of that solution. Let's say I would like to have array handling number of most distant node and distance for each node. Could You @KarolyHorvath give one more example? Please :)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in a python implementation inspired on Karolys sollution:

## Step 1: Downward only search

- **For each node** and **for each of its children**, calculate the most far away grandchild.
- **For each node** remember the **two most extended branches** we found this way.

python code:

```
def getFarGrandChild(node, tree, grandChildren):
    winner = None # {'node' : node, 'distance' : 0}
    second = None
    for child in tree.childrenOf(node):
        grandChild = getFarGrandChild(child, tree, grandChildren)
        if winner == None or grandChild['distance'] > winner['distance']:
            second = winner
            winner = grandChild
        elif second == None or grandChild['distance'] > second['distance']:
            second = grandChild

    grandChildren[node] = (winner, second)
    if winner == None:
        return {'child' : node, 
                'grandChild' : node,
                'distance' : 1}
    else:
        return {'child' : node, 
                'grandChild' : winner['grandChild'], 
                'distance' : winner['distance'] + 1}
```

## Step 2: Search in all directions

A is connected to its children and grandchildren, but also to its parent and and grandparents and their other descendants. We call these **nieces**

- **For the root**, select as most distant node: the most distant child.
- **For each of its children**, select either the most distant child or the most distant niece. **The most distance niece** is the most far away child of the root from another branche.
- **Proceed downwar**, passing as most distant niece can now come from another child or from higher up.

python code:

```
def getFarRelative(node, tree, grandChildren, farNodes, niece = None):    
    winner, second = grandChildren[node]

    if niece != None:
        if winner == None or niece['distance'] > winner['distance']:
            second = winner
            winner = niece
        elif second == None or niece['distance'] > second['distance']:
            second = niece
    farNodes[node] = winner

    for child in tree.childrenOf(node):
        if child != winner['child']:
            getFarRelative(child, tree, grandChildren, farNodes, 
                niece  = {'child' :node, 
                        'grandChild' : winner['grandChild'],
                        'distance' : winner['distance'] + 1})
        elif second != None:
            getFarRelative(child, tree, grandChildren, farNodes, 
                niece  = {'child' : node, 
                        'grandChild' : second['grandChild'],
                        'distance' : second['distance'] + 1})
```

## I created my tree

using the below code via `from graph import *`

```
# A set of data structures to represent graphs
#

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = str(name)
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
    def __hash__(self):
        # Override the default hash method
        # Think: Why would we want to do this?
        return self.name.__hash__()

class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, src, dest):
        self.src = src
        self.dest = dest
    def getSource(self):
        return self.src
    def getDestination(self):
        return self.dest
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}->{1}'.format(self.src, self.dest)

class Digraph(object):
    """
    A directed graph
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # A Python Set is basically a list that doesn't allow duplicates.
        # Entries into a set must be hashable (where have we seen this before?)
        # Because it is backed by a hashtable, lookups are O(1) as opposed to the O(n) of a list (nifty!)
        # See http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset
        self.nodes = set([])
        self.edges = {}
    def addNode(self, node):
        if node in self.nodes:
            # Even though self.nodes is a Set, we want to do this to make sure we
            # don't add a duplicate entry for the same node in the self.edges list.
            raise ValueError('Duplicate node')
        else:
            self.nodes.add(node)
            self.edges[node] = []
    def addEdge(self, edge):
        src = edge.getSource()
        dest = edge.getDestination()
        if not(src in self.nodes and dest in self.nodes):
            raise ValueError('Node not in graph')
        self.edges[src].append(dest)

    def childrenOf(self, node):
        return self.edges[node]

    def hasNode(self, node):
        return node in self.nodes
    def __str__(self):
        res = ''
        for k in self.edges:
            for d in self.edges[str(k)]:
            #for d in self.edges[k]:
                res = '{0}{1}->{2}\n'.format(res, k, d)
        return res[:-1]
```

## And tested on this tree

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a tree :
    #            root
    #           /  \
    #          l    r
    #        /  \
    #       ll   lr
    #     /       \
    #    lll       lrr
    #   /           
    #  llll          

    myTree = Digraph()
    myTree.addNode(Node(str('root')))        
    myTree.addNode(Node(str('l')))   # for left
    myTree.addEdge(Edge(Node(str('root')), Node(str('l'))))
    myTree.addNode(Node(str('ll')))  # for left, left
    myTree.addEdge(Edge(Node(str('l')), Node(str('ll'))))        
    myTree.addNode(Node(str('lll'))) 
    myTree.addEdge(Edge(Node(str('ll')), Node(str('lll'))))        
    myTree.addNode(Node(str('llll'))) 
    myTree.addEdge(Edge(Node(str('lll')), Node(str('llll'))))        
    myTree.addNode(Node(str('lr')))  # for left, right
    myTree.addEdge(Edge(Node(str('l')), Node(str('lr'))))        
    myTree.addNode(Node(str('lrr'))) 
    myTree.addEdge(Edge(Node(str('lr')), Node(str('lrr'))))        
    myTree.addNode(Node(str('r'))) 
    myTree.addEdge(Edge(Node(str('root')), Node(str('r'))))
```

## With these statements

```
    grandChildren = {}
    getFarGrandChild(Node('root'), myTree, grandChildren)
    for key in grandChildren:
        print key, grandChildren[key]
    print '\n'

    farNodes = {}
    getFarRelative(Node('root'), myTree, grandChildren, farNodes)
    print '\n'
    for key in farNodes:
        print key, farNodes[key]
```

Comment: Thanks for the challenge, Karoly and Michocio